# Multiply big floating point?

Tags: sql-server, multiplication, operation

I wanted to to multiply number in SQL Server, but it never got right, truncated or overflow

Can anyone explain how SQL Server process the value:

```
DECLARE 
    @value1 NUMERIC(38,10)=234567890123456123123.123456789123
    ,@value2 NUMERIC(38,10)=1.001
SELECT 
    a=@value1*@value2
    ,wanted_result=234567890123456123123.123456789123*1.0001
```

SQL Server can process my random data normally, but if the number is stored as [numeric] it got truncated, for [float] it overflow can anyone explain how to get [wanted_result] from table / function?

Comment: You declare `@value1` as `NUMERIC(38,10)` but your data has more than 10 digits after the decimal place. The initial value is already truncated . You initialize `@value2` as `1.001` but your `wanted_result` is multiply with `1.0001`. Fixed that and you should get same result except for the decimal places

Comment: `wanted_result` will require numeric(38,15) as per the precision and scale rules described at [Precision, scale, and Length (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql).

Comment: @Squirrel even after I fix `@value2` the value is truncated, to 6 digit length not the same to `wanted_result`

Comment: Refer to the link provided by AlwaysLearning on the Precision and Scale. The answer is there